Why am I getting a type error when getting user input (width, height) from html to flask?
Okay, so I’m trying to make an image resizer with flask and Pillow and I am done with the 1st two parts:

Show user uploaded images with Dropzone
Save user uploaded image as it is for now into a static folder

Now, I want to resize these images before saving them. For resizing them I have a form that gets width and height from the user.
Html code -
<form>
    <p>IN PIXELS</p>
    <label for="width">Width - </label>
    <input type="number" id="width" name="width" value="width">
    <label for="height">Height - </label>
    <input type="number" id="height" name="height" value="width">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>

Script that gets user image -
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def retrieve_images():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        if filename != '':
            file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] or \
            file_ext != validate_image(file.stream):
                return 'Invalid Image', 404
            img_file = Image.open(file)
            width = request.form.get("width")
            height = request.form.get("height")
            res_img = img_file.resize((width, height), Image.LANCZOS)
        return res_img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return render_template('index.html')

And, I have this type error -
return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I tried to search online but could not find any relevant answer to this.

Can you log width and height and make sure they are integers and not None?

Hey, thank you so much for helping out. As to your suggestion, how do I do that? I tried typecasting user input from string to variable but it shows that input is "NoneType".
